# Name and uniqueness of a concept

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

Consider a the gradient of a function. Starting from a point in the domain, I can follow a trajectory such that its tangent is parallel to the gradient of the function in every point.

Is this trajectory unique? What is its name?

Comment: Cool idea. So you'd be passing perpendicularly through the function's level curves?

Comment: @EliRose, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$. The gradient is $\langle 2x, 2y\rangle$, so if you depart from the origin at any angle and continue straight, you will be parallel to the gradient at any point. So the trajectory isn't unique; you'll have to choose an initial velocity.

For any function $f$, I believe we can identify one of these trajectories as a path $r(t) :: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that solves the differential equation:

$$r'(t) = \nabla f$$

If we write $r(t) = \langle x(t), y(t) \rangle$, then this means we have a system of differential equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f\\
y'(t) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f\\
\end{aligned}
$$

and we can find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$ in terms of $t$ by using the Chain Rule. I'd appreciate if someone could do that out.

As far as a name -- I don't know exactly! Certainly seems related to [gradient descent/ascent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

Comment: very interesting! Is the equality $r'(t)=\nabla f$ is required? Wouldn't it be enough that $r'(t) \times \nabla f = 0$? I have searched "gradient descent trajectory" and found some (but few) uses of this expression. Maybe you are right and this is the one I was looking for.

Comment: following the path you suggested, I found that over the trajectory $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}$. However, the resulting $y(x)$ is a function, while the trajectory discussed is not necessarily a function. Do you have any idea to continue from here?